# Parsing XML document using Acrobat X Pro (util.readFileIntoStream)

Tags: xml, acrobat

I'm try to read an XML file containing coordinates and other form meta to populate annotations over a PDF image.

I have been stuggling to get the script to read the form, let alone being parsing.

I'm fairly new to JS so any guidance is appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
app.beginPriv();
var xmldoc = util.readFileFromStream(whatever path);
var xmlstring = util.stringFromStream(xmldoc);
app.endPriv();
```

When I run this within acrobat pro, I get a "general error: operation failed" message.

Thank you

Comment: Where do you run this code? Doc-level, from a button, app-level?

Comment: doc-level from a newly added menu option

Comment: Actually, you don't need higher privileges for this at all. What you need, OTOH (if you haven't done that already) is the code for the menu item.  What you have is a string, representing the contents of your document. And now, you will have to interpret this string, using text manipulation and a bunch of Regular Expressions. E4X utilities may be usable as well, but I don't think that would be future-proof. For a quick check whether you got something useful, feed xmlstring into a multiline text field.